# Pass data to a bootstrap modal that contain bootstrap-select upon click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm new with jQuery & currently try to test passing data to a bootstrap modal that contain bootstrap-select (by Silvio Moreto). I've read the docs and try to do what I understand from the docs but it seems everything that I did failed to work as in my comprehension.

Here's the scenario, I've the page that have been loaded with data retrieved from database via PHP Laravel. In that page, there's an edit button for editing. The edit button will load a modal that contain input text and select option upon click.

Here's the page code snippet:-

```
@foreach ($cklist as $key=>$cklst)
@if (strtoupper($sort->sectionFK)==strtoupper($cklst->schSectionFK))

<?php $index++; ?>
    <tr>
        <!-- Task Name -->
        <td class="table-text"  width="10px">
            <div>{{$index }}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="table-text">
            <div>{{strtoupper($cklst->clQuestion)}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
           <!----- Edit Question Item Button ----->
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".qs-item-modal-lg" data-question="{{$cklst->clQuestion}}" data-question-id="{{$cklst->cklistPK}}" data-question-severity-id="{{$cklst->severityFK}}" @foreach ($svrity as $key=>$slct2)
                @if ($slct2->severityPK == $cklst->severityFK)
                data-question-severity-txt="{{$slct2->severityName}}"
                @endif
            @endforeach 
            class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="10px">
            <form action="{{ url('addref/'.$cklst->cklistPK) }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="schemeID" value="{{$id}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="cklistID" value="{{$cklst->cklistPK}}">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Reference</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td align="center"  width="10px">
            <form action="{{ url('delcheck/'.$cklst->cklistPK) }}" method="POST" class="delete">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('DELETE') }} 
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endif
@endforeach
```

The edit button will open a bootstrap modal (that situated in the same page) to edit that specific record. The modal code snippet:-

```
<!----- Edit Question Item Modal ----->
<div class="modal fade qs-item-modal-lg" id="editqstn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Edit Question Item</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="{{url('editquestion')}}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('PUT') }} 
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="text-left">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <h4>
                                        <label>Question Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="selectedquestion" value="">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="selectedquestionID" value="">
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <h4>
                                        <label>Severity</label>
                                        <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="svrty" name="selectedquestionSvrty">
                                            <option selected value=""></option>
                                            @foreach ($svrity as $key=>$slct2)
                                            <option value="{{$slct2->severityPK}}">{{strtoupper($slct2->severityName)}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery for passing data to modal:-

```
$("#editqstn").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {

        //get data-question attributes of the clicked element
        var slctqstn = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question');
        var slctqstnid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-id');
        var slctqstnsvrty = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity');
        var slctqstnsvrtytxt = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity-txt');

        //populate the input
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="selectedquestion"]').val(slctqstn);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="selectedquestionID"]').val(slctqstnid);

        $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(e){
            //populate the bootstrap-select selected value
            $(e.currentTarget).find('#svrty').selectpicker('val', slctqstnsvrty);
            //populate the bootstrap-select selected string text
            $(e.currentTarget).find('#svrty').text(slctqstnsvrtytxt).selectpicker('render');
        });
    });
```

I have tested the code and the data for input field is successfully passed but not the data for the select field. Therefore, I cannot provide their current selected data if users are not planned to edit them. So I wonder what's wrong in my code and hoped someone here able to oversee it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you wanted to dynamically populate the `selectpicker` value on modal render then there is an alternative approach available. You can use the `.val()` function on the base select field and then refresh the selecpicker instance.

```
$("#editqstn").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {

    //get data-question attributes of the clicked element
    var slctqstn = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question');
    var slctqstnid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-id');
    var slctqstnsvrty = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity');
    var slctqstnsvrtytxt = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity-txt');

    //populate the input
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="selectedquestion"]').val(slctqstn);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="selectedquestionID"]').val(slctqstnid);

    // Yu don't need this part
    /*
    $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(e){
        //populate the bootstrap-select selected value
        $(e.currentTarget).find('#svrty').selectpicker('val', slctqstnsvrty);
        //populate the bootstrap-select selected string text
        $(e.currentTarget).find('#svrty').text(slctqstnsvrtytxt).selectpicker('render');
    });
    */
    // Instead you can use the following-
    $(e.currentTarget).find('#svrty').val(slctqstnsvrty).selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

**Note:** I found using descriptive names in `IDs`, `classes`, `variables` etc are very helpful when I tried to debug and also in further development since easy to read and understand by team mates. Even though sometimes I work alone descriptive names help me to parse through the codes easily.

**UPDATE**

You've made a very silly mistake. In your edit button you have a `data-question-severity-id` attribute, but inside the `show.bs.modal` event callback you are trying to access this by `$(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity')`. You don't have any `data-question-severity` in the button, but `data-question-severity-id`. Updating this made it working.

Whole code snippet is the following-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4
  });
  
  $("#editqstn").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {

    //get data-question attributes of the clicked element
    var slctqstn = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question');
    var slctqstnid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-id');
    var slctqstnsvrty = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity-id');
    var slctqstnsvrtytxt = $(e.relatedTarget).data('question-severity-txt');

    //populate the input
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="selectedquestion"]').val(slctqstn);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="selectedquestionID"]').val(slctqstnid);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('#svrty').val(slctqstnsvrty).selectpicker("refresh");

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".qs-item-modal-lg" data-question="Question 1" data-question-id="123" data-question-severity-id="2" data-question-severity-txt="Severe 2" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>

<div class="modal fade qs-item-modal-lg" id="editqstn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Edit Question Item</h4>
      </div>
      <form action="{{url('editquestion')}}" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="text-left">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <label>Question Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="selectedquestion" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="selectedquestionID" value="">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <label>Severity</label>
                  <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="svrty" name="selectedquestionSvrty">
                    <option selected value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Severe 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Severe 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Severe 4</option>
                  </select>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/fm503fh9/9/

Comment: If I remove the code that you have commented, The button do not open the modal. I don't know why, but I think your method should work anyway, but it didn't. So I checked on the net, it require an event listener.

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle with the html only?

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm503fh9/6/), but here both data didn't pass... While in my page, the input text do have the data...

Comment: I just checked the Chrome's developer console, there's error stated: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).selectpicker is not a function`. So I got that a problem need to be solve first....

Comment: well you need to wrap your js code inside jquery's dom ready callback function: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // your code should be here.. })`

Comment: I have follow your updated [code](https://jsfiddle.net/fm503fh9/9/) and it works! I think you can copy the code here and I will mark it as an answer.... Anyway, thank you for your time, really appreciated...